# Hibernate and a Complex many-to-one on Two Columns

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `BUSINESS` table that looks like this:

```
BUSINESS_ID | BRN | CODE | PARENT_ID
```

A `Business` can have a `parentBusiness`, which is joined from `child.parent_id->parent.brn and child.code->parent.code` and can be represented by the query:

```
select * from business childbus left join business parentbus on childbus.parent_id=parentbus.brn and childbus.yppa_code=parentbus.yppa_code where childbus.business_id=?
```

How can I create that many-to-one relationship for `business.parentBusiness`? The following many-to-one mapping creates the link from `PARENT_ID` to `BRN` but how do I get the constraint from the `CODE` column in there?

```
<many-to-one name="parentBusiness" class="Business" column="PARENT_ID" property-ref="brn"/>
```

EDIT

It was suggested in an answer below that I try to use a `formula`. According to the docs the formula needs to return just the PK for the object and it will figure out how to populate itself. Here is where I'm at:

```
<many-to-one name="parentBusiness">
    <formula>(select parentBusiness.business_id from business parentBusiness where parentBusiness.brn=parent_id and parentBusiness.code=code)</formula>
</many-to-one>
```

But this creates an sql error

```
...
from Business business0_
left outer join Business business1_ on
    (select parentBusiness.business_id from business parentBusiness where parentBusiness.brn=business0_.parent_id and parentBusiness.code=business0_.code)=business1_.BUSINESS_ID
```

because, of course

```
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
```

How should my formula be set up?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help [link # 1](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=940270) [link # 2](http://www.alethis.net/reference/db/hibernate.html).

Comment: @Asad, I don't think I'm seeing the example which relates to my situation. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to get this complex relationship working as stated in the original question. I was, however, able to convince management that this was a poor data model.

Answer (score 2):

you could try to use the formaula attribute.
[here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column) is some documentation about how to use it...

Comment: If you want to flesh this answer out a little more it would probably be the accepted one.